# pymongo (python+mongodb) drop collection/gridfs?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Anyone know the commands to drop a collection of documents and also drop a gridfs database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To delete a collection, you can either call the [`drop()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.9%2B/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.drop) method on it, or use the [`drop_collection()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.9%2B/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.drop_collection) method on the database object:

```
my_collection = db['collection_name']
my_collection.drop()

# Or...

db.drop_collection('collection_name')
```

GridFS files are stored in a collection called `fs` by default. To delete the GridFS files, just drop that collection:

```
db.drop_collection('fs')
```

Comment: It might take a while until the effects of this command are visible :-)

Comment: In current versions of mongodb, GridFS documents are stored in two collections, 'fs.files', and 'fs.chunks'. You'd want to drop them both.